# could someone help me? OOP in C++

Tags: c++

could someone help me with my code, in line 44 I get an error when passing to the compiler since it tells me that the initializer is not declared and none of the arguments is valid. The function of my program is object-oriented in C ++, what I want to do is put information into the class adding values to those of Private, introduce them with a Cin and eject them with a Cout, could someone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Zoo{
    
    private:
        string esp;
        int id;
        string nom;
    
    public:
        
        Zoo(string, int, string);
        
        void mDatos(){
            
            this->esp = "";
            this->id = 0;
            this->nom = "";
        }
        
        void getZoologico(string _E, int _ID, string _N){
            
            this->esp = _E;
            this->id = _ID;
            this->nom = _N;
            
    }
    
};

Zoo::Zoo(string _esp, int _id, string _nom){
    
    esp= _esp;
    id= _id;
    nom= _nom;
    
}


int main(){
    
    Zoo animales[5]= Zoo( string _esp, int _id, string _nom);
    int contador = 0;
    
    do{
        system("cls");
        
        string E, N;
        int ID;
        
        cout<< "\n Especie: ";
        cin>> E;
        cout<< "\n ID: ";
        cin>> ID;
        cout<< "\n Nombre: ";
        cin>> N;
        
        animales[contador].getZoologico(E, ID, N);
        contador++;
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }while (contador < 5);
    
    system("Pause");
    return (0);
    
}
```

Comment: **Pro Tip:** C++ doesn't accepts that way you initialize something (with datatypes).

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: Use `std::vector<Zoo>` to store them and access safely instead of putting them into raw arrays and you then don't need to initialize like `Zoo animales[5] = Zoo( string _esp, ...)`.

Comment: Your line 44 is not correct C++ syntax (not just a typo). Read [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) for some example with parametric constructor. Or grab some C++ book for other examples.

Comment: Please _paste the exact error message_ and show where it is. Don't paraphrase the error, and don't make people count 44 lines into your code (or paste it into an editor) to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to use the `this->` syntax, unless the parameters have the same name as the members.  Fewer letters to type --> fewer typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your fixed program (notice `added`/`edited` comments):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>  // added - required header

using namespace std;

class Zoo {

  private:
    string esp;
    int id;
    string nom;

  public:
    Zoo() {}  // added - a default constructor
    Zoo(string, int, string);

    void mDatos() {
        this->esp = "";
        this->id = 0;
        this->nom = "";
    }

    void getZoologico(string _E, int _ID, string _N) {
        this->esp = _E;
        this->id = _ID;
        this->nom = _N;
    }
};

Zoo::Zoo(string _esp, int _id, string _nom) {
    esp = _esp;
    id = _id;
    nom = _nom;
}

int main(void) {
    std::vector<Zoo> animales(5);  // added - Creating a vector of 5
    int contador = 0;              // rooms of type Zoo

    do {
        string E, N;
        int ID;

        cout << "\n Especie: ";
        cin >> E;
        cout << "\n ID: ";
        cin >> ID;
        cout << "\n Nombre: ";
        cin >> N;

        // edited - instead of accessing directly, used at() class
        // method defined under std::vector<> to access it safely
        animales.at(contador).getZoologico(E, ID, N);
        contador++;

    } while (contador < 5);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, in case of accessing said constructor in this type of case, it should always be done like this?

Comment: @DanAvila43yt It's up to you but it's one of the finest way I guess.